# Difference between BSP Provided by Poky and meta-ti for Beaglebone black

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bsp

What is the difference provided by BSP for Beaglebone black for poky and meta-ti

`poky/meta-yocto-bsp/conf/machine/beaglebone-yocto.conf` provides the Machine configuration for Beaglebone black in poky source code

`meta-ti/conf/machine/beaglebone.conf` provides the Machine configuration for Beaglebone black in meta-ti layer.

I was able to build and run the image generated by Poky on Beagle bone black . What is the advantage of meta-ti BSP Layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very detailed answer from over 5 years ago:
https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-October/021818.html